# Flutter: dynamic_timeline - how to add an Item in runtime

Tags: flutter

I am using [dynamic_timeline 0.1.2](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_timeline) in Gantt Chart view and I want to add an item to the calendar view.
I am dragging an iteam from outside into it and want that item to be visible there.
The DynamicTimeline has a globalkey assigned, where I call back to the functions and want to position the item.

I am currently trying it with:

```
(_myWidgetKey_DTIT_head.currentWidget as DynamicTimeline)
            .children.add(
            AppointmentItem(
                startDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 7, 00, 0), 
                endDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 8, 00, 0), 
                position: 0, 
                text: "HUHUHU", 
               ));
```

but there is no change to the widget.
Has anyone else tried to use the dynamic_timeline package?